# Very loud CD/DVD drive. Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, video, dvd, video-player

*Firstly I have to aoplogize for any mistakes, I am not native English speaker. But I will try my best to tell what is happening.*

When using Windows XP my CD/DVD drive was working normally as long as I was watching movies in `Windows Media Player`. When watching a movie with any other program, it was extremely loud.

Now I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and obviously I have no `Windows Media Player`. I am using VLC and my CD/DVD drive is not working normally. What can be wrong?

Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution (?)**

Check mplayer's man page.
Now this may sound trivial and silly, but mplayer is a featureful  piece of software.

For example, there is this (for DVD):

```
-dvd-speed <factor or speed in KB/s> (DVD only)
              Try  to limit DVD speed (default: 0, no change).  DVD base speed
              is about 1350KB/s, so a 8x  drive  can  read  at  speeds  up  to
              10800KB/s.   Slower speeds make the drive more quiet, for watchâ
              ing DVDs 2700KB/s should be quiet and fast enough.  MPlayer  reâ
              sets the speed to the drive default value on close.  Values less
              than 100 mean multiples of 1350KB/s, i.e. -dvd-speed  8  selects
              10800KB/s.
              NOTE:  You  need  write  access  to the DVD device to change the
              speed.
```

And then the same for CDDA:

```
-cdda <option1:option2> (CDDA only)
              This option can be used to tune the CD Audio reading feature  of
              MPlayer.

              Available options are:

                 speed=<value>
                      Set CD spin speed.
```

**Workarounds**

- You could try mplayer and cache the video file.
  But don't do this, as this would eat up all the memory you have.
- You could just rip or read in the disc before watching it.
  If the noise bothers you even at this period, reading the disc gives you the option to specify read speed. If I recall correctly, K3B had this option included.
- Get an external HDD or DVD. HDD is a better investment.
  You can store enough movies for your lifetime on a HDD nowadays.

**Disclaimer**
I have no DVD or CD drive connected, so I could not test these out.